# scrlttr2 remove toaddress

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I'm adapting a cover letter template that I found online. It takes "letter" quite literally by laying out the toaddress such that it will fit in an envelope. However, I'm going to be emailing this around and so a toaddress is redundant. I'm wanting to remove it, and move the content up. Below is a stripped down version of the code that I'm using, and attached is an image showing what I'm wanting to do. I'm an absolute LaTeX beginner, and I'm hoping what I'm wanting to do is sensible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off,foldmarks=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbol
\usepackage{csquotes}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address\\City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{012 345 678}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{beginner@latex.com}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{Name}

\setkomavar{firsthead} {
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[1mm]
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\scshape Job title } 
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company\\Address\\City}

\setkomavar{subject}{Position Title}
\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
Content goes here.

Sincerely yours, \\ \\ \\
\usekomavar{signature}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Have you read the manual of `scrlttr2`, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script, it contains substantial information about changing the formatting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off,foldmarks=false,parskip=half,addrfield=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbol
\usepackage{csquotes}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont}
\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{\parskip}
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\makeatother

\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address\\City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{012 345 678}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{beginner@latex.com}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{Name}

\setkomavar{firsthead} {
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[1mm]
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\scshape Job title } 
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company\\Address\\City}

\setkomavar{subject}{Position Title}
\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
Content goes here.

\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Note, that I've not only added two changes of pseudo-lengths (you can find these in figure 22.1 and table 22.1 of scrguien.pdf of [current KOMA-Script version](http://www.komascript.de/current)), but also added option `addrfield=false`.

Comment: Thanks so much!